# get the most two recent dates for each customer

Tags: sql, postgresql

basically, I need to retrieve the last two dates for customers who purchased in at least two different dates, implying there are some customer who had purchased only in one date, the data has the following form

```
client_id  date
1          2016-07-02
1          2016-07-02
1          2016-06-01
2          2015-06-01
```

and I would like to get it in the following form

```
client_id      previous_date     last_date
1              2016-06-01        2016-07-02
```

remarques:

a client can have multiple entries for the same date

a client can have entries only for one date, such customer should be discarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rank your dates with `DENSE_RANK`. Then group by client_id and show the last dates (ranked #1 and #2).

```
select
  client_id,
  max(case when rn = 2 then date end) as previous_date,
  max(case when rn = 1 then date end) as last_date
from
(
  select 
    client_id, 
    date, 
    dense_rank() over (partition by client_id order by date desc) as rn
  from mytable
)
group by client_id
having max(rn) > 1;
```

Comment: Well, I just noticed my answer doesn't add much, as xQbert has already posted about the same (albeit with minor flaws in it).

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED:

We use a common table expression to assign a row number based on the date in descending order and then only include those records having a row number <=2 and then ensure that those having 1 row are excluded by the having.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Distinct Client_ID
       , Date
       , row_number() over (partition by clientID order by date desc) rn 
  FROM Table)

SELECT  Client_ID, min(date) previous_date, max(date) last_date)
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <=2 
GROUP BY Client_ID
HAVING max(RN) > 1
```

Comment: Looks quite fine. Change `row_number` to `dense_rank` for there can be duplicate dates. And insert `GROUP BY Client_ID` before the `HAVING`clause. And remove the prenthesis after `last_date`.

Comment: I suppose I could distinct the date since the expected results didn't seem to want the duplicate dates.  or would I have distinct first then get the row number.  I'm never quite sure about that order of operation until I do it.  but dense rank is likely faster than my approaches.

Answer (score 1):

<s>All you need is a group by...</s>

```
--test date
declare  @tablename TABLE
(
    client_id int,
    [date] datetime
);

insert into @tablename
values( 1 , '2016-07-02'),
   (1 , '2016-07-02'),
   (1 , '2016-06-01'),
   (2 , '2015-06-01');

--query
SELECT client_id,MIN([DATE]) AS [PREVIOUS_DATE], MAX([DATE]) AS [LAST_DATE]
FROM @tablename
GROUP BY client_id
```

Updated

```
-- create data
create table myTable
(
    client_id integer,
    given_date date
);

insert into myTable
values( 1 ,  '2016-07-02'),
   (1 ,  '2016-07-02'),
   (1 , '2016-06-01'),
   (1 , '2016-06-03'),
   (1 , '2016-06-09'),
   (2 , '2015-06-01'),
   (3 , '2016-06-03'),
   (3 , '2016-06-09');

-- query
SELECT sub.client_id, sub.PREVIOUS_DATE, sub.LAST_DATE
FROM
 (select 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.client_id order by b.given_date desc,(MAX(b.given_date) - a.given_date)) AS ROW_NUMBER,
   a.client_id,a.given_date AS PREVIOUS_DATE, MAX(b.given_date) - a.given_date AS diff, (b.given_date) AS LAST_DATE
    FROM myTable AS a 
      JOIN myTable AS b
        ON b.client_id = a.client_id 
    WHERE a.given_date <> b.given_date
    group by a.client_id, a.given_date, b.given_date) AS sub
WHERE sub.ROW_NUMBER = 1
```

Comment: If you are going to down vote my asnwer, be man enough to say way so I can fix it..

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, your query will select clients with only one date, too. And it will return a wrong result for clients with more than two dates. Brackets around names are non-standard. I think SQL Server and MS Access use them, but hardly any other DBMS. PostgreSQL doesn't.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Thanks. I work in T-SQL for the more part, just started back on here and didnt' notice postgresql tag. Also, to me the request is not as clear, but after reading your comment and some of the other post I reworked my script. can test it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55677.

Answer (score 1):

build up:

```
t=# create table s153 (c int,  d date);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into s153 values (1,'2016-07-02'), (1,'2016-07-02'),(1,'2016-06-01'),(2,'2016-06-01');
INSERT 0 4
```

query:

```
t=# with a as (
select distinct c,d from s153
)
, b as (
select c,nth_value(d,1) over (partition by c order by d) last_date, nth_value(d,2) over (partition by c order by d) prev_date
from a
)
select * from b where prev_date is not null
;
 c | last_date  | prev_date
---+------------+------------
 1 | 2016-06-01 | 2016-07-02
(1 row)
```